# I need to know how to use popen to call the program bc, then how to give bc an equation from a string

Tags: string, popen, solver, bc

I've been looking up the basics of bc and popen for hours now, and nothing can definitively tell me how I can use them together in a script. I am asking here not because I want some encouragement and reassurance that breaking down the problem will help me solve it. I need to know *these specific things*, because *I cannot find this information anywhere*, and I do not have the time, energy, or patience to beat my head against a wall for hours.

I am trying to write a code that can recieve an equation as a string, and this equation will be random, so the *best way to solve it* is to give it to bc. I also know that it will be in a format in the string that bc can undertand.

So far, I have this:

```
{
FILE *eq;
char eqstr[256];
char cmd[256];

eq = popen("bc *", "r");
if(eq == NULL)
{
exit(1);
}

while(fgets(eqstr, sizeof(eqstr), eq) != NULL)
{
strcpy(cmd, "echo '");
strcat(cmd, eqstr);
strcat(cmd, "' | bc");
}
pclose(eq);
return 0;
}
```

I need it to not print the result in the terminal, but to return the result to the code to be compared with the correct answer. The instructions and methodology of the test are *extremely* vague, so I have no clue how I check that the answer is right. This is a small part of a much larger code that is causing me so much grief.

If you can't show me an example code that solves my problem, at least recommend a website I can look at that might have the answers.

Comment: `popen` is unidirectional -- you can either pass data to a child OR read data back.  You CANNOT do both.  If you want bdirectional communication, you must do something else, either using files or manually creating pipes and forking.